# Composing a vector as the sum of unit vector in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

in the question: compose the vector $(3, 1, 4)$ as a sum of the unit vector in $\mathbb R^3$, would solving this problem require taking the length of the vector and dividing the length to each element in the vector as the $ i, j$, and $k$ values?

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

$(3 \, 1\, 4)=3 (1\,0\,0)+ (0\,1\,0) +4(0\,0\,1)=3i+j+4k$

Answer (score 0):

It depends which basis you are using.

A basis is three vectors, say $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$, which we can use to express every point in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

One example would be one metre left, one metre forward and one metre up.

The triple $(3,1,2)$ only makes sense when you have a basis. That is because, *by definition*,

$$(3,1,2) = 3\vec{u} + 1\vec{v} + 2\vec{w}$$

Usually, we take $\vec{u} = \widehat\imath$, $\vec{v} = \widehat\jmath$ and $\vec{w} = \hat k$, where $\widehat\imath$, $\widehat\jmath$ and $\hat k$ are the unit vectors pointing along the positive $x$-, $y$- and $z$-axes, respectively.

If you are already using the basis $\widehat\imath$, $\widehat\jmath$ and $\hat k$ then
$$(3,1,2)=3\widehat\imath+1\widehat\jmath+2\hat k$$

If you use the basis $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ then you write $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ in terms of $\widehat\imath$, $\widehat\jmath$ and $\hat k$:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\vec{u} &=& u_1\widehat\imath + u_2\widehat\jmath + u_3\hat k \\
\vec{v} &=& v_1\widehat\imath + v_2\widehat\jmath + v_3\hat k \\
\vec{w} &=& w_1\widehat\imath + w_2\widehat\jmath + w_3\hat k
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: If the OP was confused to start with, I can't imagine what state they will be in after reading this hodgepodge.

Comment: @TonyK My post answers the OP's question and containes extra information. If the OP stops reading after line five then s/he has all of the information s/he needs. My answer is of some use and hence is not "not useful". Your downvote is unfair. You are welcome to vote how you choose, but you should follow the guidelines.

Comment: @Fly by Night I agree that this pretty much answers the question, although only the OP can decide, but I might add that $(3,1,2)$ *does* make sense as an element of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @GPerez The coordinates $(3,1,2)$ are in relation to a basis. You need to know which way to go, and how far to travel for $(3,1,2)$ to make sense, i.e. to uniquely define a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$. For example, I could change all of the numbers on the doors in your street. You'd still know where to go to get home, but you would be going to a different house number.

Comment: @FlybyNight I would say yes, and I would say no. Yes because if indeed we mean that $(3,1,2)$ is a *vector* then yes, this is a coordinate representation relative to some coordinate system, and as always we need to know which. However $\mathbb R^3$ is also just $\mathbb R^3$, before anyone gives it a vector space structure, and its elements are just humble ordered triples of real numbers, who don't know anything about linear combinations. Right?

Comment: @FlybyNight To clarify, we could also say that $\mathbb R^3$ is actually an *affine* variety, and therefore we must specify an origin.